# How do I turn the "character count" off in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have no idea what this is or how it got turned on. It wasn't "on" when I turned off my comp on Friday, but it's here today. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: You're talking about the strange "10x", correct?

Comment: @DanielB yah. I just figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it. This is something the Power Mode extension offers. For whatever reason the extension's "Shake" and "Combo" was flipped on, which results in the 10x indicator. You can remove that in the settings here:

[image]

Comment: @DanielB thanks for that info

Comment: @DanielB 2 days :/